# Meaning of 具体的に

Tags: grammar, meaning

What is the meaning of 具体的に? Usage of particle `に` in this context is not very clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

具体的に means "practically"　or more literally "concretely." The addition of the に changes 具体的 to function adverbially.

Comment: Some examples would be very nice.

Comment: @ErnestasGruodis [Here are some examples on ALC](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%85%B7%E4%BD%93%E7%9A%84%E3%81%AB&ref=sa)

Comment: I don't think 具体的に is considered a 副詞 (which is a word class in Japanese, not a description of how something is syntactically behaving). It is just considered the 連用形 of the 形容動詞.

Comment: It doesn't become a 副詞 but it does become a 連用修飾語.

Comment: @snailboat interesting. does this correction suffice?

Comment: @DariusJahandarie is this correction sufficient or still off?

Comment: @virmaior Seems accurate to me.